# Buffon needle in higher dimensions

Tags: probability, paradoxes

Imagine a stick of length 1, and also a floor with evenly spaced lines, such that the distance between neighboring lines is also 1. If one throws the stick on the floor, there will be certain probability that stick crosses a line on the floor. Finding that probability is known as [Buffon needle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle).

It turns out that the probability involves $\pi$, and that was really a surprise, and an enigma, for a long time, since there is no circle, or anything circular or curved, involved in problem statement.

*Is there a 3D equivalent of Buffon needle?*

*Does the probability in such case involve $\pi$?*

*What about N-dimensional equivalent of Buffon needle?*

Comment: Googling on "buffon needle 3d" led to http://www.mikepuddephat.com/Page/1600/Single-object-stereology-(part-2)

Comment: I don't see the result (the probability) there. @Barry

Comment: VividD, he gets a probability $\ell/2h$.  There's no $\pi$.  (The corresponding 2d result is $2\ell/\pi h$.)

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I must misunderstood him. Anyway, its crazy - it doesn't involve $\pi$. But how about a unit square and parallel planes in 3d?

Comment: Regarding no-circle-involved: If you throw a lot of needles and then put the resulting lines on top of each other (same center) you do get a circle. So there is really a circle in the problem, its just a bit hidden.